# Is it possible to create a linked list of nodes with no data in them and populate the data later in c++

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to write a c++ program which asks the user how many nodes are needed and then takes that input to create a linked list of that many nodes. I want to populate those nodes with data later. Is that possible?
Traditional Linked List examples populate the data while creating the nodes.

Comment: you can use a default value when you create your nodes or do not initialize the data part when you create. What is the type of your data ?

Comment: Absolutely. That's part of the beauty of a linked-list's design.

Comment: I'm trying to create a list that holds in each node, a fruit's name and its weight in the data part of the node. so i will need to have a string and an int/float in the data part. any idea how i can create a list of let's say 10 empty fruit nodes - each node containing placeholders for the name and the weight of the fruit - and then populate the data using user inputs?

Comment: You can do pretty much whatever you want. _How_ will depend on your design & code, which we can't see or know.

Answer (score 0):

If the "data" is default constructible and assignable, then you can create nodes with default constructed data, and assign it later.

If the type does not allow that, or that is otherwise problematic, then another approach is to use `std::optional<data_type>` as the data.

This applies to all data structures.

Note that while it may be possible, creating the nodes first and assigning the data later is typically not useful. A simpler, and more typical approach is to create the nodes while populating the list.